# Differential criterion for regular sequences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a subalgebra of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.
Suppose $\theta=(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_p)$ is a sequence of of elements in $R$. If I want to test for their algebraic independence, I have a simple differential criterion: compute the Jacobian matrix $(\frac{\partial\theta_i}{\partial x_j})$ and find at least one maximal minor which does not vanish identically as a polynomial in the $x$'s. Now I am interested in the stronger property of $\theta$ being an $R$-regular sequence. Is there a similar criterion I could use? I don't mind if it is complicated involving higher derivatives, jets and whatnot, but it would have to be rather concrete and explicit. The motivation for my question comes from my [recent work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11147) on rings of invariants.

Comment: Whether $\theta_i$s are algebraically independent did not depend on $R$, only in the polynomial ring. But, regular sequence is very much dependent on $R$, so conditions as elements of the polynomial rings will be insufficient. May be as an example, consider $\mathbb{C}[x^4, x^3y,xy^3,y^4]=R$. Then, $x^4, y^4\in R$ do not form a regular sequence in $R$, but in the polynomial ring, they do.

Comment: @Mohan: +1. Yes I know my question is a bit ill-formulated at the moment, precisely for the reason you mentioned. I guess one needs some info about the ring $R$ is but I would have to think more what that missing hypothesis for $R$ should be. If this helps, the example of $R$ I am interested in, is the ring of invariants of some reductive group like $SL_2$.

Comment: I should add: this is about how should $R$ be given? Giving $R$ in terms of generators is useless for my purposes. Maybe the image of a Reynolds operator, which in theory I know how to compute, is much better.